# How to use own php variables in wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress template in php like this:

```
<?php
include('wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
?>

...Hello World...

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

ok, it works good... but the contents of title and other meta tags are empty. How can I change the header contents or use my own $variables inside the get_header() section? it doesnt work like this:

```
$test="Blabla";
get_header();

.. inside a wordpress header template:
echo $test;
```

the $test variable is empty :(.. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Post the contents of file `wp-blog-header.php` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $test variable is empty because the header is included by a function, hence effectively 'in' the function, and more importantly, in a different scope.. think of it like

```
function get_header()
{
  $test = '1234';
}
get_header();
echo $test; // won't work because test is in a different scope
```

you can however use globals, or $_SESSION variables, or create a static class to hold variables in that can be called from anywhere.

the global option is probably the quickest fix here (not necessarily the strictest though).

```
$GLOBALS['test'] = "Blabla";
get_header();

.. inside a wordpress header template:
echo $GLOBALS['test'];
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

put all your different custom function and/or variable in your functions.php

or replace
get_header();
by
include get_bloginfo("template_url").'/header.php';

Comment: and thumbs up for @nathan explanation

Comment: Don't include via URL when you don't have to - "include get_bloginfo("template_url").'/header.php';" use `include TEMPLATE_DIR . '/header.php';` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace:

```
<?php 
$test="Blabla";
get_header(); 
?>
```

with:

```
<?php 
$test="Blabla";
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/header.php');
?>;
```

and the variable will be in scope. Try to avoid using globals.

Answer (score 0):

By default get_header() pulls the header.php file. you could simply rewrite the header.php file to include what you want. If you don't want to rewrite it for all templates but for only a few you could use get_header('name') which would grab header-name.php in which you could have your own items.