# Wordpress Title Inside Header

Tags: wordpress, page-title

I'm tyring to change how the title works within the header.php file on Wordpress. At the moment I have it so it will display out the name of each page the user is on, which works well, apart from on pages that load blog posts.

I'd like it set so the "title" element within the header.php file can cope with custom names too i.e. instead of loading the name of the latest blog as the title when you visit the blog page I want it to just say Blog.

I decided to create my own variable and then using header check to see if that has been set, but I can't get it to work, placing it either before or after the call to the header file.

index.php

```
$header_title = "Blog";
get_header(); ?>
```

Then inside the header.php file I have the following code.

```
<title>
April Kelley | 
    <?php if (isset($header_title)) { 
        echo $header_title;
     } else {
        the_title(); 
    }?>
```

Now to my mind this should work, so where am I going wrong?

PS. I only intend to use this $header_title variable on certain pages like index.php and seach.php where the pages pull in the blog posts themselves, so will isset still return false is the variable cannot be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way of doing this is to use [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter, you don't need to modify template, e.g. :

```
function my_title($title, $id) {
    if (is_home())
        $title.= ' | Blog';

    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'my_title');
```

If you really want to use your own var, you should read this : [How to use own php variables in wordpress template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211305/how-to-use-own-php-variables-in-wordpress-template)

Comment: would that work? I ask because my homepage is a static page and not the blog page itself?

Comment: Then you should use is_front_page

Comment: In the end I went with the global variable option you linked too, to save time, but will go back and look at your other soloution when time is not so tight.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
the_title();
```

as

```
echo get_the_title()
```

hope this work for you

Comment: that wouldn't work, i'm trying to set the variable in a different file so that the title can be set for all pages from within the header file.