# wordpress header includes no show in other pages

Tags: php, wordpress

i try use include in the header.php of my theme in wordpress

In this include i have simple vars , as for example $data_1="My site" or $data_2="My Site 2" , are examples no more and you can supose go into this include file

The problem it´s for example wordpress call this header in each case with function wp_header();

And if i put this include in the header.php with these values or others , this values no show in the others pages , if you for example include this in header and create template as header body and footer php , always show this values but problem it´s wordpress use wp_header() function for load this header

How i can fix this issue ?

Thank´s , regards

Comment: maybe [do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) can help you

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one might help: [How to use own php variables in wordpress template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211305/how-to-use-own-php-variables-in-wordpress-template)

To save you clicking(!), here's the answer to that issue:

The $test variable is empty because the header is included by a function, hence effectively 'in' the function, and more importantly, in a different scope.. think of it like

```
function get_header()
{
  $test = '1234';
}
get_header();
echo $test; // won't work because test is in a different scope
```

you can however use globals, or $_SESSION variables, or create a static class to hold variables in that can be called from anywhere.

the global option is probably the quickest fix here (not necessarily the strictest though).

```
$GLOBALS['test'] = "Blabla";
get_header();

.. inside a wordpress header template:
echo $GLOBALS['test'];
```